# Stripping lines from text file with Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to remove specific lines from a text file.  The text file is just a list and I want to remove specific entries if they are present.  So what I have is this:

```
$f=${path_to_file}
for($i = 0; $i -le $f.length; $i++)
{
    if ($f[$i] -eq "text_to_be_deleted")
    {
        $f[$i]=$null
    }
}
${path_to_file}=$f
```

The problem is that this is stripping out all the carriage returns from the text file.  I tried the following:

```
(type path_to_file) -notmatch "text_to_be_deleted" | out-file path_to_file
```

The problem with that command is that I may have a string such as "abc", "abcd", or "abcde".  If I have "abc" in the quotes", it deletes any line containing "abc", not just an exact match.  I really suck at regular expressions so I couldn't figure out how to specify an exactly this string.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be accomplished with a one-liner:

```
(type path_to_file) -notmatch "^text to be deleted$" | out-file path_to_file
```

Note that the `^` means 'start of the line' and the `$` means end of the line.

Comment: Note that you may want to specify an encoding to `Out-File` in case some programs choke on UTF-16.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using non-PowerShell tools:

```
findstr /V /C:"abcd" file.txt > file_new.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got most of it.

```
$f=${path_to_file}
for($i = 0; $i -le $f.length; $i++)
{
    ## If NOT EQUAL to text-to-be-deleted, print to file
    if ($f[$i] -ne "text_to_be_deleted")
    {
        ## write to file, preserving carriage returns.
        out-file -filepath ${path_to_file} -InputObject $f[$i] -append
    }
}
```

It uses out-file in a different way than you are, but it should preserve CR's.